# GAE datastore will not persist owned 1:1 relationship within embedded JDO class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus, object-persistence

I have three @PC classes:

```
@PersistenceCapable
class A {
  @PrimaryKey @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
  private String                  id;

  @Persistent @Embedded
  private B b;

  public void setB(B b){
    this.b=b;
  }
}

@PersistenceCapable @EmbeddedOnly
class B {
  @Persistent
  private String someInfo;
  @Persistent
  private C c;

  public void setC(C c){
    this.c=c;
  }
}

@PersistenceCapable
class C {
  @PrimaryKey @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
  private String                  id;

  @Persistent
  private String value;

  public void setValue(String value){
    this.value=value;
  }
}
```

I want to achieve that B is persisted to same entity as A while holding a reference to C but GAE does not let me, I get a following exception on commit:

```
Detected attempt to establish A(1) as the parent of C(2) but the entity identified by C(2) has already been persisted without a parent.  A parent cannot be established or changed once an object has been persisted.
```

in this code:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
c.setValue("foo");
b.setC(c);
a.setB(b);

m.makePersistent(a);
```

additionally: a look into DatastoreViewer shows me that C has been persisted! But A is missing. This might happen because I do not explicitelly rollback the transaction on exception which is not relevant in this case, but reveals that C is written before its parent A.

what am I missing? Tx

**Update 2:**

as suggested I have enabled transaction explicitely:

```
Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
try {
  tx.begin();
  pm.makePersistent(a);
  tx.commit();
} finally {
  if (tx.isActive()) {
    tx.rollback();
  }
  pm.close();
}
```

same exception was thrown as when doing .makePersistent() w/o explicit transaction. Then I set disabled the global cross tx option in JDO config:

```
<property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="false"/>
```

and now get a different exception with a possible hint:

```
cross-group transaction need to be explicitly specified, see 
TransactionOptions.Builder.withXGfound both Element {
  type: "A"
  id: 1
}
and Element {
  type: "C"
  id: 2
}
```

Comment: Would you please show the code attempting to persists your data?

Comment: I've updated the question. I know I don't use the transaction explicitelly, however according to google docs that should work, too.

Comment: you added "makePersistent" to your post, but ... with *what object*? and what lifecycle state is the C in when you do call that? The log tells you all of those things

Comment: yes, its not obvious, you're right, I've completed the code. But why it attempts to write C before persisting A although knowing that C's parent reference has to be updated afterwards? Or even more iffy why does C need to reference A, whereas A (transitively thru B) owns C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok FINALLY I got the point,

yet I think that DataStore's JDO implementation ( I don't know if its DataNucleus job) miss there something. According to [transactions on DataStore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions) usually only entities along an ancestor can be persisted in one go, exceptionally GAE *claims* to support Cross-Group Transactions which is limited by number but can persist unrelated entity paths. Both did not apply in my case.

The *poor* solution is now to enforce unowned relationship via a Key (GAE proprietary), which is the only possible kandidate to describe ancestor path so that DataStore gets it right is following extension to my POJOs:

```
class A {
  ...
  private String naturalPK;
  public String getNaturalPK(){
    return naturalPK;
  }
  ...
}

class C {
  ...
  public void setId(String id){
    this.id=id;
  }
  ...
}
```

and the persistency-code:

```
  tx.begin();

  // we have to assign parent/child keys to enforce ancestor path
  Key parentKey = KeyFactory.createKey("A", A.getNaturalPK());
  a.setId(KeyFactory.keyToString(parentKey));

  // now build child key
  a.getB().getC().setId(KeyFactory.createKeyString(parentKey, "C", A.getNaturalPK()));

  pm.makePersistent(offerer);
  tx.commit(); // works.
```

one issue is that I cannot use surrogate keys here, the other thing is that I dont want non-JDO and non-BO code to be in my POJOs, so the parent-child relationship has to be established somewhere in die JDO-DAO implementation. I suppose that DataNucleus GAE port is doing somewhat inaccurate here as the persistency graph looks to be reversed :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're problem vanishes if you set up a transaction boundary for this to work. Although the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Relationships_Entity_Groups_and_Transactions) claims that what you do should be possible, I assume you have set `datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns` to `true` in your `jdoconfig.xml`.
Thus, `C` is stored in its own transaction with an entity group of it's own. In a second transaction, you store `A` and thus try to reassign `C` to `A`'s entity groupy which is forbidden:

> because entity groups can only be assigned when the entities are created

So: set up a transaction (as recommended).

Comment: thanks, I checked it but yet no success (updated my question)

Comment: It might help to create the objects after the transaction was established. The GAE/JDO combination sometimes cares for funny nuances...